# Fiddler4 does not capture Nox Android Emulator traffic

Tags: android, fiddler

I am using the NoxPlayer Android Emulator and am trying to capture HTTP/S traffic with Fiddler4, which is also running on the PC that Nox is running on.
I have set Fiddler as a proxy, which I can confirm working as ipv4.fiddler:8888 in the Browser returns the Fiddler Echo Page and other pages show a certificate error.

From there I have installed the Fiddler Root certificate, which stopped the Certificate Error from showing.
All internet traffic works on the Emulator now, but the requests do not show in fiddler.

All filters are disabled and "Allow remote connections" is enabled.

How do I fix this?

Comment: So you have installed the Fiddler root CA certificate on the virtual Android device? What apps do you try to capture traffic from? Read also this article: https://blog.netspi.com/four-ways-bypass-android-ssl-verification-certificate-pinning/

Comment: All Traffic works perfectly fine on the device, no difference noticable from before adding fiddler proxy.
I added the fiddler cert, Certificate warnings were showing when running http requests before i installed it, that stopped after installing the cerificate.
The fiddler page works in the emulator, so it should be in the fiddler proxy and working, but the traffic does not show in fiddler.